# Handling addition of data to existing array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function named `getPageContent` which lists sections, sub sections and resources within them. My output isn't quite right as Volvo XC60 is currently sitting under the Vauxhall section instead of Volvo. Can someone help point me in the right direction? The line of code which I'm wresting with is:

```
$sections[$section_index]->subsections[$section_index]->subcontent[] = $subContent;
```

**Expected hierarchy**

- Cars (Section)

  - Car Guide (Section resource)
  - Vauxhall (Sub Section)

    - Vauxhall Corsa (sub section resource)
    - Vauxhall Astra (sub section resource)
  - Volvo (Sub Section)

    - Volvo XC60 (sub section resource)

**Function**

```
public function getPageContent($id)
{
    $sections = $this->Pages_Section->get($id);
    $groupIds = [1,2,3,4];

    foreach ($sections as $section_index => $section) {
        for ($y = 0; $y <= 5; $y++) {
            $sections[$section_index]->content[$y] = [];
        }

        $subSections = $this->Pages_Section->order_by('position')->getwhere(['sections_parent_id' => $section->id]);
        if (is_array($subSections) && $subSections !== []) {
            foreach ($subSections as $subSection) {
                $sections[$section_index]->subsections[] = $subSection;
                $subSectionContents = $this->Pages_Sections_Resource->getbysectiongroups($subSection->id, $groupIds);
                foreach ($subSectionContents as $subIndex => $subContent) {
                    if ((int) $subContent->pages_sections_id === (int) $subSection->id) {
                       $sections[$section_index]->subsections[$section_index]->subcontent[] = $subContent;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $contents = $this->Pages_Sections_Resource->getbysectiongroups($section->id, $groupIds, $type);
        foreach ($contents as $content) {
            if ($content->year >= 0 && $content->year <= $programmeYear) {
                $sections[$section_index]->content[$content->year][] = $content;
            }
        }
    }

    return $sections;
}
```

**Array currently returned in `$sections`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1273
            [pages_id] => 190
            [sections_parent_id] => 0
            [name] => Cars
            [subsections] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1274
                            [pages_id] => 190
                            [sections_parent_id] => 1273
                            [name] => Vauxhall
                            [subresources] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 
                                            [pages_sections_id] => 1274
                                            [resources_id] => 28701
                                            [name] => Vauxhall Astra (resource)
                                            [year] => 0
                                            [pagesectionresource_id] => 11004
                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 
                                            [pages_sections_id] => 1274
                                            [resources_id] => 28699
                                            [name] => Vauxhall Corsa (resource)
                                            [year] => 0
                                            [pagesectionresource_id] => 11002
                                        )

                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 
                                            [pages_sections_id] => 1275
                                            [resources_id] => 28702
                                            [name] => Volvo XC60 (resource)
                                            [year] => 0
                                            [pagesectionresource_id] => 11005
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1275
                            [pages_id] => 190
                            [sections_parent_id] => 1273
                            [name] => Volvo
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use the same `$section_index` as the index on both `$sections` and `$subsections`.

Comment: What are `this->Pages_Section` and `$this->Pages_Section_Resource`? If you're using a common framework, please add the tag for it.

Comment: Your code creates a `content` property in each element of `$sections`. Why doesn't this show up in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$sections[$section_index]->subsections[$section_index]->subcontent[] = $subContent;
```

to

```
$subSection->subcontent[] = $subContent;
```

Your code is using `$section_index` as the index into the subsections array, but that's the index of the current element of `$sections` and has nothing to do with the subsections array.